# Color set up in the css differs from the displayed one

Tags: css, colors

I set backround color to #2560d2 for both divs. I took a screenshot of the page displayed in Chrome and checked the color in the Photoshop. It is different - #3766ce. Why?

(In my second div I tried with -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact but it didn't help.)

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #2560d2
}
```

```html
<div class="test">My test</div>
<br />
<div class="test" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact">My test with exact color adjust</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

"Assign the monitor profile. Then convert to sRGB. A screenshot is in monitor color space. It has already been remapped for display, and the RGB values recalculated. You only get the same reading if monitor profile and document profile are identical - which they normally shouldn't be."

Adobe Community Professional, Aug 10, 2017

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/photoshop-pasted-screenshot-colors-off-with-the-last-update/td-p/9270682?page=1